# GWT LayoutPanel children events not working

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Hi I have an issue with GWT client side where events not being received by widgets when their parent, somewhere along the tree, is using GWT LayoutPanel or any of the Layout containers.

Here is a demonstration with simplified code.

This code works:

```
    LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel();

    layoutPanel.add(new SimplePanel());
    layoutPanel.add(new Button("Button1"));

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(layoutPanel);
```

The button is highlighted on hover, and attached ClickHandler receives events.

However the code below does not. Only change was reverse the add() to layoutPanel order:

```
    LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel();

    layoutPanel.add(new Button("Button1"));
    layoutPanel.add(new SimplePanel());

    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(layoutPanel);
```

The button is drawn, but no events are dispatched, not even the ':hover' events are getting through. Inspection of the generated HTML shows the 'button' tag is being generated.

I am using GWT 2.8.2, Google Appengine 1.9.66 and Java 8 (appengine-web.xml configured for version 2 and Java8 JRE).

I have a much more complicated GUI that is having the same issue, I just boiled it down to the above example to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't specify any layout option to the added widgets, you're actually overlaying them on top of one another, so in the second case the button is behind the simple panel, which is transparent so I doesn't visually hide the button.